# Bitwise And for Int[] One Liner

Tags: java, arrays, bitwise-and

Can anyone help me find a method of taking the bitwise and (&) function of every element in an int[] in a single line? For example, [1,3,8,9] would be 1&3&8&9.  I am trying to make a constructor for a class that calls another constructor so I can't use a multi-line solution.

Comment: you don't need one-liner, you can call another static method, probably in some other util class

Answer (score 2):

you don't need one-liner for this task, it is better to use separate method (probably static in separate util class), anyway you can use:

```
Arrays.stream(array).reduce((a,b) -> a&b).getAsInt()
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was trying to keep my code relatively compact but maybe using a static method will make more sense

Comment: If you want a compromise between compactness and a static method, you could define a `private static ToIntFunction<int[]> anded = array -> Arrays.stream(array)...`.